# Hausdorff dimension of the relative complement of a set contained in a $G_\delta$

Tags: general-topology, fractals, hausdorff-measure, fractal-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis

We have the following result:

> [Every set is contained in a $G_\delta$ set of the same Hausdorff dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130172/every-set-is-contained-in-a-g-delta-set-of-the-same-hausdorff-dimension)

I was wondering how tight can this inclusion be made, complement-wise. Is true that:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an analytic set. Then there exists $A \subseteq G \in G_\delta$ such that $dim_\mathcal{H}(G \setminus A) = 0$

If not, what if $A$ is required to be a Borel set or even $F_\sigma$? Any advice on finding a counterexample? And any comments about dimensions of relative complements are appreciated.

Comment: First, let's do the case of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.  The obvious attempt give us a $G_\delta$ set $G \supset \mathbb Q$ with Lebesgue measure $0$.  But that is far from Hausdorff dimension $0$.  Can we even get a $G_\delta$ set $G \supset \mathbb Q$ with Hausdorff dimension $1/2$?

Comment: @GEdgar According to the linked result, G could be chosen so it has dimension zero, which admittedly sounds strange to me for a dense $G_\delta$, but I find no error.